# How to do encryption/decryption in xml with StAX?

Tags: xml, security, encryption, stax

One of the reason I use StAX is because of it low memory consumption in processing large xml files.

I've been requested to encrypt the whole xml files, and decrypt them later.

The easier solution I can come up with, without having major change to existing code, is encrypt content only.

```
        xsw.writeStartElement("row");
        xsw.writeCharacters(Encrypter.encrypt("z"));
        xsw.writeEndElement();
```

However people still can understand the structure of the data. 
What if I want to encrypt everything in xml? Any Solution? 
Bear in mind that I am dealing with large xml file :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CipherInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html)/[CipherOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) and pipe your StAX stream through it, IMO it'd be more efficient and secure than encrypting values only.